# PostgreSQL : ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL, and I have the following code

```sql
select unnest(xpath(
    '//ns2:ProcedureCategory/text()',messagebody::xml,
    array[array['ns2','urn:wco:datamodel:WCO:DEC-DMS:2']]
))::text
from sw_customs_message scm 
where unnest(xpath(
    '//ns2:ProcedureCategory/text()',messagebody::xml,  
    array[array['ns2','urn:wco:datamodel:WCO:DEC-DMS:2']]
))::text = 'H7'
```

and I get the error message

SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE
Position: 172

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set returning functions should be used in the FROM clause. Then you can also reference the result columns in the WHERE clause:

```
select u.val::text
from sw_customs_message scm 
   cross join unnest(xpath('//ns2:ProcedureCategory/text()', 
                     scm.messagebody::xml,  
                     array[array['ns2','urn:wco:datamodel:WCO:DEC-DMS:2']])) as u(val)
where u.val::text = 'H7'
```

---

Note that typically `xmltable()` is easier and more flexible to use if you want to turn an XML value into rows and columns. And if you are storing XML in a column, the column should be defined as `xml` not something else.

Comment: on the same XML i would like to extract also another value ns2:FunctionalReferenceID . how i can do it ?

Comment: @LucaRuggeri: as I said: `xmltable()` is typically much easier to use. But that is a totally different question now (and not really answerable without proper sample data)